# What does "in" mean in "in Him all things hold together", Col 1:17?

Tags: word-study

"And he is before all things,and in him all things hold together". Colossians 1:17 ESV

"I form light and create darkness". Isaiah 45:7.

"God is light, and in him is no darkness at all". 1 John 1:5

How can all things hold together "in" him if there is no darkness "in" him?

[1 John and Colossians verses quoted both have Greek "en", so KJB use of "by" might need explaining rather than be an explanation].

Comment: Hi C. One of the site requirements for posts is to identify the Bible version that you are working from. In this case it is particularly important as you are asking about the English translation. Can you please click on the "edit" link underneath the tags and indicate the version? In fact, perhaps you could quote the passage instead of just supplying the address. And when you have a minute you might want to take the site tour:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Possibly related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13182/is-colossians-117-an-allusion-to-sirach-4326

Comment: The KJV translates εν αυτω as 'by him' whereas Young's Literal has 'in him'.

Comment: http://www.gffg.info/Jesus/CorruptedBibles.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I form the light, and create darkness: I make peace, and create evil: I the Lord do all these things". KJB

"You shall surely die". Genesis 2:17.

Man can see darkness and evil as against man's interest because for man they result in death.

"God raised him up". Acts 2:24.

Evil is never good for its own sake but God can use evil. God used evil to prove that it has no power over Christ, by raising him.

"you meant evil against me, but God meant it for good". Genesis 50:20.

God using evil does not make it good. It is still evil.

If God has a way of making good come from evil, then evil is part of his thinking. That which is in his thoughts is "in Him".

Answer (score 2):

Colossians 1:

> 15 The Son is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn over **all creation**. 16 For **in him all things were created**: things in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or powers or rulers or authorities; **all** things have been created through him and for him. 17He is before **all** things, and **in** him **all** things hold together.

The word "all" appears 5 times in these 2 verses. The phrase "in him" appears twice.
Paul depicts a unifying and universal framework in which all created things exist. All normal matter, dark matter, and dark energy exist in this universal framework.

Is there anything outside of this framework?

No, except the uncreated God himself.

1 John 1:

> 5 God is light, and in him is no darkness at all.

This metaphor refers to God as a person, not as the universal framework. God is a moral agent as a person.

How can all things hold together "in" him1 if there is no darkness "in" him2?

him1 refers to the universal framework; him2 refers to the moral agent of God.

Answer (score 2):

This section seems to run out of superlatives when describing Christ and what he does, which is why it's a mistake to try to isolate one short verse. Try starting from verse 13 and going through to verse 29. That little word 'in' crops up 16 times. Also, twice the word 'mystery' is written, for Paul is trying to convey a mystery that God is making known, in Christ. Or, you could equally say, 'through' Christ, or 'by' Christ. Time and again that little word 'in' has such a magnitude of meaning that ***it could equally be rendered 'through' or 'by'***. Paul is struggling to find enough superlatives to convey the immensity of who Christ is and what he does.

When we home in on the verse in that section which speaks of the mystery of "Christ in you, the hope of glory" (vs.27), we begin to see how it is the immensity of Christ relating to us (Christian believers) that gives us that intimacy of belonging to him to the extent that we cannot be separated from Christ (Romans 8:35). Likewise with the mystery of marriage, where the two become one flesh and "What God has yolked together, let not man separate (Matthew 29:6). These help show what it means for all creation to be held together in Christ.

Christ permeates, binds together, infills, indwells, sustains, maintains... all of those things. That applies to individual Christians as much as it does to the material creation. Whether you think of outer space or the way atoms hold together, Christ is the agent involved.

This is where Hebrews 1:2-3 adds to our understanding of Colossians 1:17. Of his Son, we learn that God

> "...hath appointed [him] heir of all things, by whom also he made the
> worlds; who being the brightness of his glory, and the impress of his
> presence, and upholding all things by the word of his power, when he
> had by himself purged our sins, sat down on the right hand of the
> Majesty on high... (KJV)"

It's too mind-blowing for us to fathom, this side of eternity. ***As all things hold together by the word of his power, then if Christ with-draws his word of power, it follows that all things will dissolve or break apart***. That is just what 2nd Thessalonians implies (chapter 2) where another mystery is mentioned, when the wicked one shall be revealed then "the Lord shall consume with the spirit of his mouth and shall destroy with the brightness of his coming". Then in 2 Peter ch.3 we learn further that the day of the Lord is coming when "the heavens shall pass away with a great noise, and the elements shall melt with fervent heat, the earth also and the works that are therein shall be burned up" and "all these things shall be dissolved". **That will be when all those things no longer hold together**. They will dissolve prior to him then creating a new heaven and a new earth, in which righteousness shall dwell.

**By contrasting this event where things no longer hold together with how all things currently hold together, we can understand what Col. 1:17 means.** This shows the immensity of the power of the word of Christ.

Answer (score 0):

The King James Bible reads: 
"And he is before all things, and by him all things consist."

The meaning is, that they are kept in the present state; their existence, order, and arrangement are continued by his power. If unsupported by him, they would fall into disorder, or sink back to nothing. If this be the proper interpretation, then it is the ascription to Christ of infinite power - for nothing less could be sufficient to uphold the universe; and of infinite wisdom - for this is needed to preserve the harmonious action of the suns and systems of which it is composed. None could do this but one who is divine; and hence we see the reason why he is represented as the image of the invisible God. He is the great and glorious and everactive agent by whom the perfections of God are made known.